# Add where condition in SQL randomizing query

Tags: mysql, sql, max, where-clause

Is it possible to add a WHERE condition in the below SQL query?

At the moment I am picking a random row from all rows into `table` and I need to change it so that i can get a random row only from the rows in `table` where  column: `type="1"`

This is the SQL query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table AS r1 JOIN
       (SELECT (RAND() *
                     (SELECT MAX(id)
                        FROM table)) AS id)
        AS r2
 WHERE r1.id >= r2.id
 ORDER BY r1.id ASC
 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: How do you form this query? It already has a `where` clause; you could probably extend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add the condition.  Do be careful, though, because you may not get any matches:

```
SELECT *
FROM table r1 JOIN
     (SELECT (RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table)) AS id
     ) r2
WHERE r1.type = 1 and r1.id >= r2.id
ORDER BY r1.id ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

This might also have a big impact on performance.  For performance, you would want an index on `table(type, id)`.  Also, you might as well include the `where` in the subquery as well:

```
SELECT *
FROM table r1 JOIN
     (SELECT (RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table WHERE type = 1)) AS id
     ) r2
WHERE r1.type = 1 and r1.id >= r2.id
ORDER BY r1.id ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, Gordon for the suggestions. I will use the second one, since the first does not return anything if the random row has type different from 1.